# Django で指定した時間にブログを投稿したい

Tags: python, python3, django

Django で（`models.DateTimeField` で）指定した日時に、保存した記事を公開するには、`views.py` をどのように書けばいいのでしょうか？

現在は `views.py` を、

```
def hoge(request):
　　post = POST.objects.order_by('-published_date')[0]
　　return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'post': post})
```

としているため、公開日（`published_date`）が最新の投稿が、日時に関係なく（未来の日時でも）表示されています。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/108076